# Exact match with sql like and the bind

Tags: java, sql, jpa, sql-like

I have a bind in the SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%?%'
```

the bind set the `?`.

Now, if i want to search with like method everything work but if, without change the sql, i want to search the exact match i dont now how to do.

I tried some regexp int the textbox es:
_jon \jon\ [jon] and some others but nothing work properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this question about SQL or JPQL (and JPA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to

```
select * from users where name like '?'
```

If you want to do a wildcard match, put the wildcards as part of the string that you're binding to the variable.  If you don't want to do a wildcard match, then don't.

Note that `like` and `=` have the **same performance** *except* when your wildcard character is first in the string (for example, `'%bob'`) as in that case the query optimizer can't use indexes as well to find the row(s) that you're looking for.

Comment: re: like and = having the same performance : in mysql that's true, but OP doesn't mention which sql s/he is using...

Comment: @oedo : It's the same in pretty much every modern rdbms.  It *used* to be different in a few, but thankfully optimizers have gotten smarter.

Answer (score 0):

you can't search an exact match if the sql contains % symbols, as they are wildcards. you'll need to change the sql to

```
select * from users where name = '?'
```

for an exact match

(you can also use `select * from users where name like '?'` but that's more inefficient)

Answer (score 0):

What is keeping you from changing the SQL?

The Like condition is for 'similar' matches, while the '=' is for exact matches.