# Generating a dymamic sql SELECT statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm having some small trouble trying to dynamically generate an SQL SELECT statement generated from an entry from a webpage.
Basically i have a small search engine in the website, it accepts three parameters (price,city,brand), so i have a JavaBean built in the same way with only 3 attributes, the same ones.
When performing a SELECT on the database i could make it this way using PreparedStatement

```
String sql=select * from product where price<=? and city=? and brand=?;
prep=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
prep.setDouble(1,price);
prep.setString(2,city);
prep.setString(3,brand);
```

where prep is of course a PreparedStatement obj
My problem comes when the user does not insert a parameter in the field of the web page, because apparently he is not interested on a limitation.
I need to find a way to "cut" the entry at runtime, like:

city field=""? then take out city from the search criteria:

```
String sql=select * from product where price<=? and brand=?;
```

One way i could do that is filling in the code in the servlet with else-if but thats not the only solution i'm sure.
Another potential solution would be to use IFNULL(expr1,expr2) function of SQL but in case is null, then i should just remove the null-field from the query.

Do you have any advice?

i hope its clear enough the way i explained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OR` in your `WHERE` clause to do something like:

```
WHERE (Price<=? OR ? IS NULL)
AND   (City = ? OR ? IS NULL)
AND   (Brand = ? OR ? IS NULL)
```

Comment: Did you test it? SQL is fine, but I'm not sure if MySQL and/or its JDBC driver allows setting prepared statement values like that.

Comment: @balusc - Sure didn't.  I'm a SQL guy not a java guy :)  I was hoping to show him a workaround to get to the same place he was aiming for without having to dynamically truncate the SQL string.

Comment: suppose Price is not like ?, i think then mysql will look for a Price column whenre the value is NULL, which is not the case, because the value of ? is simply another value then the one given, but its not a NULL.

Comment: @Jboy - if you don't define a `Price` variable in your code, what is the result?  Is it not a `NULL`?  What would get passed to the query for `Price`?

Comment: @JNK hi, ok clear, i could finally try it, this is the statement i wrote: String sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE (name=? OR ? IS NULL)";    and unfortunatelly, the exception i get: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2    while debugging i see that the parameter goes through correctly, so it reaches the prepared statement, but it looks like preparedStatement expects a parameter for it (i mean the ? after the OR) p.s i tryed it at home with a simple bean called user but the concept is the same as described in the main topic above

Comment: @JBoy - OK.  As I mentioned, I'm not a java guy, I'm a `SQL` guy.  If you can find a way to pass a `NULL` variable the syntax above should work.

Comment: @JNK hey, FOUND IT!! it was as simple as logic: String sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE (name=? OR ? IS NULL)"; and then:  pre.setString(1, name); pre.setString(2, name); basically i only had to tell him to set to null the second parameter if its not exactly the same as the provided name, THX!

Comment: @Jboy - happy to help, glad you figured out the java portion! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace condition "=" with Like '%[input_value]%'. In this way if uset left blank field you don't have any restriction.

Comment: Grazie Alessandro, indeed as Balusc is saying, i need something for the double value of price too :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use `like` for strings.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE price <= ? AND city like '?' AND brand like '?'";
prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
prep.setDouble(1, price);
prep.setString(2, city);
prep.setString(3, brand);
```

See [Exact match with sql like and the bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904401/exact-match-with-sql-like-and-the-bind)

And in case city/brand is not selected, then set it

```
prep.setString(2, "%");
prep.setString(3, "%");
```

If price is not selected, then use some very big number.

Comment: Syntax is wrong and even if it was correct, it won't work for prices.

Comment: Also the SQL Syntax is NOT correct.  You need wildcards for a `LIKE` comparison...

Comment: Using: String sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE %"; and then pre.setString(1, "%"); gives me: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: @JNK No you need not to use wildcards with like. You can make exact search with like. `name like 'John'`
@JBoy sql string should end with ? instead of %. `sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE ?"`